# Are there any mingw-w64 builds that supports GCC plugins?

Tags: windows, gcc, gcc-plugins

I've been using builds from [mingw-builds](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds) on windows for a long time, but I'd like to experiment with [GCC plugins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), which is not supported by mingw-builds project. So I tried searching for some other builds that support it, but couldn't find any. Is GCC's plugin feature fundamentaly broken on windows or something? Do you know if any one builds mingw-w64 with plugin support (--enable-plugin)? I think that something like gcc-melt or gcc-python-plugin would be very interesting on windows as well.

PS: and no, I don't really want to build it myself, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW-w64 build, that supports plugins, can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tumagcc/files/0.8a/), by this time it is GCC 4.7.3 and is built with working LLVM's dragonegg set of plugins.

Answer (score 2):

There is one you can use [[Mingw-users] gcc --enable-plugin experimental built on windows](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28248366%29), It was supplied by xunxun years ago, I can build GCC plugin dlls with this GCC compiler suite.